# How to Copy a settings from a Cloth object to multiple Cloths objects (e.g. Physics Properties > Cloth > Object Collisions > Distance)

Tags: objects, physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I have a scene with multiple cloths objects. I want to modify something in physics properties to all others objects (same settings for Object Collisions>Distance); Something similar with "Copy from active";

Or it is possible to copy and paste a settings to multiple cloths objects or to select all and apply same settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Blender has an addon in the preferences menu called: Copy attributes.  This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pr_2MQK5Fow shows how to use it, and it sounds like it does exactly what you are wanting